# Capturar datos de los compradores para usarlos luego

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, mercadopago

Mi problema es que quiero que una vez que se haya hecho el pago, (mediante checkout pro), de alguna forma me lleguen los datos de quien compro, su email, nombre, direccion, y demas... pero no se como hacer para que esos datos me lleguen, es decir, una vez que el pago se haya hecho con exito, se me manden los datos del comprador para poder manejar la compra.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.